# setting no cache for different parts of spring mvc 3 using WebContentInterceptor?

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc, cache-control, interceptor

Hi there I have developed a dynamic web application that uses Ajax to fetch data from databases and keep the GUI up to date but while testing it with IE8 I am experiencing caching issues.

I used the following code in my webmvc-config.xml file to stop the browser from caching:

`<mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean id="webContentInterceptor" 
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
        <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
        <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
        <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
    </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>`

and it works exactly as it should, but the problem is that now the browser obviously doesn't cache anything.  what I want to know is how to modify that xml code so that it applies to the Ajax parts of the web app (which are controlled using 5 Controller files); so that the icons..etc are still cached? The path to these controller files would be something like "/admin/**"

I know that the Spring WebContentInterceptor has properties such as "setCacheMappings" and "setPathMatcher" but there is nowhere online that I can find examples of these being using in the xml config file.

ANY help would be much appreciated, it's really doing my head in.. Thanks. Jake

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your `<mvc:interceptors>` you can restrict the URL path each interceptor should apply to, as follows:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mapping path="/admin/*"/>
        <bean id="webContentInterceptor" ..... />
    </mvc:interceptor>
<mvc:interceptors>
```

It's all explained [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-interceptors).

Comment: Great, thanks Costi that worked perfectly. nice link too. you can also add multiple mapping paths in the same interceptor and then any <property> you include in the interceptor will be applied to all the paths (for anyone who is having this problem and has stumbled across this post).